# Connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database to which is normally connected to via GlobalProtect using .NET 6 application

Tags: sql-server, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I'm using .NET 6, Azure Function version 4 and SqlClient in my Azure Function application.

I have a connection string like this

```
Server=tcp:name.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dbName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=120;
```

Normally, I access this database using GlobalProtect by providing it portal, username and password.
Now, I'm developing an Azure Function app which will access this database, but I'm getting this error

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
> MyAzurefunction. Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Cannot open
> server 'serverName' requested by the login. Client with IP address
> 'MyIpAddress' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable
> access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run
> sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule
> for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes
> for this change to take effect.

I know I'm getting this error because my IP Address doesn't have access to the server but how can I connect to it via my Connection String?

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/hybrid/azure-functions-hybrid

Answer (score 0):

I create azure SQL database. connection string of database:

```
Server=tcp:<serverName>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<database Name>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=server;Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I created function app with .net 6 in visual studio.
Image for reference:

[image]

[image]

I published it to Azure.
Image for reference:

[image]

Selected the ellipse(...) on the published page and selected **Manage Azure App Service settings**.
Image for reference:

[image]

Click on Add Setting in Application page and add the name of setting.
Image for reference:

[image]

In sql_connection enter the connection string of sql db in Local section for remote section click on Insert Value from Local.
Image for reference:

[image]

Install System.Data.SqlClient package in Manage Nuget packages of project. I added below code that connects to SQL Database :

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[FunctionName("DatabaseCleanup")]
public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("*/15 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    // Get the connection string from app settings and use it to create a connection.
    var str = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("sqldb_connection");
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var text = "UPDATE SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader " +
                "SET [Status] = 5  WHERE ShipDate < GetDate();";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
        {
            // Execute the command and log the # rows affected.
            var rows = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            log.LogInformation($"{rows} rows were updated");
        }
    }
}
```

Above function runs every 15 seconds to update the `Status` column based on the ship date.

I added my IP address in database firewall settings.
Image for reference:

[image]

At 15 seconds after startup, the function runs.
Output of number of rows updated in the SalesOrderHeader table:

[image]

In this way I connected to my SQL database to my function app.

Comment: You added your IP address in database firewall settings but I don't have master db access. Hence, I cannot add firewall settings.